# kdb - Simplifying a query with maps and lj

Tags: kdb

I have few tables already loaded into memory

```
//the real table is huge
st:([] s:`a`a`a`b`b`b;n:3 5 7 3 5 7; v:`U20`U30`U50`U22`U33`U44)

//step function
st1:`s#select first v by s,n from st

//mapping function 
f:{  (st1([] s:(),x 0;n:(),x 1))`v}

/Another table
t:([] s:`a`b`b;v:4 6 8)

//user input
MAP:([ KEY:`U20`U33`M40 ] VAL:200 330 440 )
```

Is there a way to simplify the following one? Here I am creating a temporary column `KEY` for `lj` and then deleting it

```
delete KEY from (update KEY:first each f each (s,'v) from t) lj MAP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can convert the user input (currently it's keyed table) to a dictionary

```
MAP2:`U20`U33`M40!200 330 440
```

The new query with `MAP2`:

```
update VAL:MAP2@f each (s,'v) from t
```

Actually, the following is bit simpler and faster:

```
update VAL:MAP2@f ( s;v) from t
```

Answer (score 3):

Can do it by one line by and avoid the f by forming tables to index into other tables. This should vectorize it and make it faster by avoiding the each both join and each(s) in your final line

```
q)update VAL:MAP[([]KEY:st1[([]s;n:v);`v]);`VAL] from t
s v VAL
-------
a 4 200
b 6 330
b 8
q)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not sychronise your column names so that you can do direct key-table lookups?

```
q)st:([] s:`a`a`a`b`b`b;v:3 5 7 3 5 7; KEY:`U20`U30`U50`U22`U33`U44)
q)st1:`s#select first KEY by s,v from st

q)t,'MAP st1 t
s v VAL
-------
a 4 200
b 6 330
b 8
```